# how i can get the value of y-axis from CGPoint

Tags: core-plot

i am Chinese, my English is very poor, this is my first question
here is my code

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(UIEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
//i want get the value of y-axis or x-axis from the point!
{
```

is there has api to get it or i must count it by myself

waiting your answer 
think you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the plot space:

```
NSDecimal dataPoint[2];
[space plotPoint:dataPoint forEvent:event];
```

or

```
double dataPoint[2];
[space doublePrecisionPlotPoint:dataPoint forEvent:event];
```

After this method call, `dataPoint[CPTCoordinateX]` will hold the x-value and `dataPoint[CPTCoordinateY]` will hold the y-value.